# Java reading/writing several objects to file

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

I'm trying to learn how to use steams and I can't seem to figure out.
The thing I'm trying to do is add several separate objects to a file then retrieve them all at once. 
When I try to retrieve them I only get the "last" inserted object. For now I'm trying to figure out how to print the objects but later I would like to import them into an ArrayList for example.
Here is my code:

```
public class ExpenseDB {
private final static File DB = new File("C:\\Expense2s3.dat");

public static void addExpense(Expense ex) throws AddException {
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream out;
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(DB));
            out.writeObject(ex);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Added "+ex);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new AddException();
        }
}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void getAllExpenses() {
    if (DB.length() == 0) return;
    try {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(DB));
        try {
            Expense exp=(Expense)in.readObject();
            System.out.println(exp);
            in.close();
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the issue here

Answer (score 1):

When you open a file and then write to it, it will overwrite its contents. instead use [`new FileOutputStream(DB,true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream-java.lang.String-boolean-) to append to the end of the file

Comment: Did you mean FileOutputStream?

Comment: Yep it worked :)
How about the InputStream? Can I get it to loop over the objects or do I have to import them all at once?

Comment: @Airwavezx readObject() will only return one object at a time so you will have to loop to get them all.

Comment: This won't really work. Each `ObjectOutputStream` will output its header before writing the object. This will result is a file that consists of gibberish and can _only_ be read by spawning `ObjectInputStream` in a loop, one for each object. The correct way to do this is to persist a `Collection` or use a structured representation like XML.

Comment: Exactly as Boris said, I tried `Expense exp=(Expense)in.readObject(); while (exp != null){` which did not work.
If I insist in doing it in a loop and not using a Collection how do I do that?

Comment: @Airwavezx with great difficulty. In between the buffers embedded in `ObjectInputStream` and `FileInputStream` it's very error prone to create new `ObjectInputStream` on the same `FileInputStream`. You could potentially use a `FileChannel` and set the position to read each object. I would avoid this pain if possible. It's actually a rather complex problem to keep any collection in a file and update it without just rewriting the whole lot.

Comment: Hey Boris, I still am not sure how to get this done. Could you refer me to a similar code which would help me out? 
Whether it's on how to rewrite the whole file every time I need to add an object, or on how to convert my file to a Collection.